# Per project sbt repositories/config

Tags: scala, sbt

I work with a variety of SBT projects and not all of them share the same repositories/resolvers. I would like to be able to store the repositories configuration inside each project so that I can also build other people's projects without overriding the default (or theirs) repositories and sbt configuration.

Using the `~/.sbt/repositories` is not an option since that is per user and not per project. I have tried passing parameters to sbt and that works; e.g. `sbt compile -Dsbt.boot.properties=build/sbt.boot.properties`. However, that requires people to remember this flag and type it/alias it every time.

Is there any way to get sbt to read configuration, or flags like the above, from its current directory? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html?

> Resolvers for Maven2 repositories are added as follows:
>
> `resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"`
>
> This is the most common kind of user-defined resolvers. The rest of
>   this page describes how to define other types of repositories.